# Timeline-like presentation software?

Tags: presentation

For some presentations I'm working on, I don't want to swap out the entire slide at once - I want to change parts of it (like keeping a list on one side static and expanding on each part on the other side).

Doing this in something like Powerpoint/Google Slides, I have to stack up all the text boxes on the changing side and add animations to swap them in and out. It gets the job down, but it's a massive pain to edit the text content here, since they're all on top of each other.

It seems like the best way to handle this would be a presentation editor where you can choose parts to change at each step along the way without having them necessarily be discrete slides, sort of like editing your presentation along a timeline.

Does anything like this exist? (Preferably on Linux or web-based. Also preferably free.)

**Note**: [Prezi](https://prezi.com/) is all about zooming in and out on one giant canvas. I'm more interested in something that basically lets you continuously update/iterate a single slide.

Comment: Maybe [Prezi](https://prezi.com/) works for you

Comment: Prezi is all about zooming in and out on one giant canvas. I'm more interested in something that basically lets you continuously update/iterate a single slide.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but I've been impressed with D3JS. Googling it comes up with http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034 and https://github.com/jiahuang/d3-timeline and many other examples.